# Using for loops to create an upside-down triangle

Tags: java, for-loop

Im a java student, and i'm have quite the hard time, trying to use for loops to create an upside down triangle.

This is what my code looks like now, a straight forward triangle. How can i make another one just like it, but upside down?

```
for (int i=1; i<20; i += 2)
    {
        for (int k=10; k < (0 - i / 2); k++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Is that tricky?

Just change

```
for (int i=1; i<20; i += 2)
```

To

```
for (int i = 19; i >0; i -= 2)
```

Code.

```
 for (int i = 19; i > 0; i -= 2) {
     for (int k = 10; k < (0 - i / 2); k++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println("");
   }
```

Out put:

```
 *******************
 *****************
 ***************
 *************
 ***********
 *********
 *******
 *****
 ***
 *
```

Comment: Im sorry to say that this doesn't help me at all. To get the formation to actually move down is no problem, adding the spaces, that's the problem. I can't have it looking like that, i need a full, upside down, triangle :s

Comment: @JanØyvind you can edit your question and put what are you looking for(expected out put)

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = 2*lines;
for (int i = lines-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    for (int j = i; j < lines; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++)
    {
        if (k % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(symbol);
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
    c -= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change your 3rd for loop

```
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

In your code, you print 1 star, 3 stars, 5 stars and so on... (i stars actually)

To make it upside down, start the j at the max value and decrement it so you print n - i stars

```
       for (int j = 20 - i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i += 2) {
        for (int k = 10; k < (0 - i / 2); k++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.reverse());
}
```

However you are probably supposed to learn something about loops and the algorithm.